# How to apply color for path for horizon chart using d3js?

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to create horizon chart to populate multi year data all at once to identify problem via visual representation but below code is not working, please help to correct it, similar code is working in section 2 in this post.

[1] How  to apply color for path for horizon chart using d3js?

```
data=[0.2,1.3,1.1,1.3.0.9]

        var color =
            d3.scale.threshold()
                .domain([0,1])
                  .range(["green", "yellow", "red"]);       
        path.enter().append("path")
                    .style("fill", function (d,i) { return color(i);})
                    .attr("transform", t0)
                    .attr("d", d0);
d3.transition(path)
.style("fill", function(d,i) { return color(i); })
    .attr("transform", t1)
    .attr("d", d1);
```

[2] However same is working for below code:

```
var color = d3.scale.threshold()
      .domain([7, 9])  
      .range(["green","yellow","red"]);  

    var svg = d3.select('body')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width',500)
        .attr('height',200);

    svg.selectAll('rect')
        .data(d3.range(10))
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('x',function(d,i) { return i * 40; })
        .attr('y',30)
        .attr('width',30)
        .attr('height',30)
        .attr('fill',function(d,i) { return color(i); });
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Are there errors? Are you trying to correct colors in the scale? Or is there another issue, like positioning or transitioning?

Comment: Thanks Andrew for paying attention, in my source to draw horizon chart, i want to color based on threshold value so that i can control color.At present, colors are not applying as per my logic as in section 2 :: 0.01~7 : green
8,9: yellow
10: red
Same pattern i want to apply for horizon chart. but its not applying as per current logic. i found difference is svg and path in section 1 and 2. hope i clarify my question in detail.

Comment: what is difference if apply ".attr('fill',function(d,i) { return color(i); });" on svg or path ?

Comment: I want to apply logic in source at  https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/blob/master/horizon/horizon.js.

Comment: This line `.style("fill", function(d,i) { return color(i); })` refers to the index (`i`) of the item in the selection, not the datum. You want to style the line based on the property: `color(d.propertyUsedToColor)`. But without seeing the rest of the code there may be other issues related to the color

Comment: Many Thanks Andrew! Pls review logic at     
 source URL: https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/blob/master/horizon/horizon.js

Is there any error? 
I am trying to restrict color based on data selection. 0<d<1 -> yellow, d>=1-> red, d<0-> green

Comment: Did you change the line referenced above? I don't see anything wrong with Jason's code regarding color. I would need to see more of your code to definitively provide a solution (I'm not sure what your data structure is, what the selection is of). Not being able to replicate the problem makes it difficult to answer.

Comment: Yes, I applied suggested changes, but unable to control color in github.com/d3/d3-plugins/blob/master/horizon/horizon.js, with scale.threshold giving black color and with scale.linear its giving transition of color based on mean value of data. I want to control color based on data.Pls suggest. data structure used is- {Date: MMDDYYYY , Value: 0.01~3.0}

Comment: Many thanks Andrew!! I am using this URL: https://gist.github.com/syntagmatic/7612dd3c35eeddf51a0b and want to control color same as fiddle at jsfiddle.net/pjrc0yy3/1. Your help will be highly appreciated :)